# Serverless framework TypeError: e is not a function

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I'm using `serverless-framework` to schedule tasks in AWS.

My application structure is

```
|- src
   |- tasks
      |- analytics.task.js
|- tasks.js
|- serverless.yml
```

The contents of `analytics.task.js`

```
module.exports.run = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Getting data...');

    console.log('success');
};
```

Removed all other codes from the run method for testing purpose.

content of `tasks.js`

```
const analyticsTask = require('./src/tasks/analytics.task');

module.exports.analytics = analyticsTask.run();
```

and content of `serverless.yml`

```
functions:
  analyticsDataProcess:
    handler: tasks.analytics
    description: 'Send analytics data to the backend server'
    events:
      - schedule:
          name: analytics-data-process-task
          description: 'Send analytics data every minute'
          rate: rate(1 minute)
          enabled: true
```

But when running the task, it is giving an error

```
{
    "errorMessage": "e is not a function",
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "TypeError: e is not a function",
        "    at /home/user/code/user/qcg-app/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:88073",
        "    at resolve (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:692:30)",
        "    at Promise._execute (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:411:9)",
        "    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)",
        "    at new Promise (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)",
        "    at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocalNodeJs (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:645:12)",
        "    at AwsInvokeLocal.invokeLocal (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:155:19)",
        "    at AwsInvokeLocal.tryCatcher (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)",
        "    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:641:10)",
        "    at _drainQueueStep (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:97:12)",
        "    at _drainQueue (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)",
        "    at Async._drainQueues (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)",
        "    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)",
        "    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)",
        "    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)",
        "    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)",
        "    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:120:23)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay there seems to be a few things going on here.

First, it's expected that your handler returns a function that can be called by lambda. In this case, you're calling the handler instead of returning the function to be called by lambda.

To solve this problem, remove the parenthesis after `run` in `task.js`

```
const analyticsTask = require('./src/tasks/analytics.task');

module.exports.analytics = analyticsTask.run;
```

There's another issue - lambda handlers need to be asynchronous functions. So you'll need to add `async` in front of the function exported as `run` in `analytics.task.js`. Now you can remove the callback argument.
The alternative would be to omit async, but actually call the callback. Since we tend to prefer newer node syntax, let's remove the callback arg in favor of async.

```
module.exports.run = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('Getting data...');

    console.log('success');
};
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this error can be caused by misspelling the function name in the serverless configuration.

Answer (score 9):

Aurelia W mentioned it in a comment but I wanted to post it since it was the answer for me. Make sure your function name matches what is in serverless.yml.

It's too bad the error isn't more descriptive.