# Serverless framework: All of a sudden receiving "ERROR TypeError: e is not a function" after deployment of service

Tags: javascript, serverless-framework

Dear Stackoverflow community,

I am using the serverless framework to deploy my JS services to AWS. It always worked perfectly but since today, after deploying a little change to one of my functions' code, I am receiving the following error when calling any function in the service:

```
ERROR   TypeError: e is not a function
    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:137343)
    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)
```

I do not understand where this comes from. I did not change the serverless.yml at all, also I did not change any basics of the function code (only a small change in an SQL statement, has nothing to do with the JavaScript code at all). I have read the following question [Serverless framework TypeError: e is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58623612/serverless-framework-typeerror-e-is-not-a-function) but nothing described there fits to my situation.

Some more context information:

- I have a microservices architecture with multiple services being deployed separately via serverless framework
- At the moment only one of my services shows this problem. First I had only deployed one function via `sls deploy -f ...` - after the deployment, the error described above popped up for that one function. Then, for testing purposes, I deployed the whole service again via `sls deploy`. Now all functions in the service raise the error described above when being invoked remotely (either via `sls invoke -f ...` or when calling the functions via the API).
- The error does not occur when calling the functions locally via `sls invoke local -f ...`.
- Also I tried to redeploy a different service to make sure it is not a general serverless issue - after redeploying the other service, the functions in that other service can be called without any problem. The error does not occur here.
- I tried to make a diff of the two serverless.yml files and also of the function files of the different services just to make sure I did not accidentially include some typing error but everything looks perfectly fine.

Does anybody have an idea where this might come from all of a sudden?

EDIT 1: I have also already upgraded the serverless framework - did not help

EDIT 2: The strange thing is that this problem occured all of a sudden while I had not changed any code - that's why I did not think posting any code would help. Now I am also experiencing this problem in further services that I want to deploy. I cannot deploy any function any more. As soon as I deploy a single function or a full service that did not have the issue before, the issue arises there as well. @PatrykMilewski: I checked the Lambda console and what I realized is that after deploying, the file that contains my function ("function.js") IS EMPTY whereas for services that had been deployed previously, the file IS NOT EMPTY. I would assume this might be the reason for the error message. Could this be caused by a bug in the serverless framework?

EDIT 3: I just remembered that I recently upgraded Mac OS to the latest version including new XCode Command Line Tools v13. From a time perspective, this could coincide with the issue popping up - could this be related to the problem?

EDIT 4: Some more environment information:

From my operating system:

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.6
BuildVersion:   20G165
```

From Serverless console output:

```
Operating System:          darwin
Node Version:              16.10.0
Framework Version:         2.10.0 (local)
Plugin Version:            4.1.1
SDK Version:               2.3.2
Components Version:        3.3.0
```

Comment: It's really hard to debug code you can't see. The error message shows you the file, row and column where the error occurs, please show some code around that line.

Comment: Two most common mistakes, that might be related to your issue:
1. Path to handler in function definition is wrong
2. Path to handler is ok, but artifacts uploaded to AWS have different structure than you expect. Simply open Lambda console and check in the code, if handler is where you expected it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Together with the very helpful support from the serverless team, I was able to resolve the issue. The reason for the issue actually was an outdated serverless version which I was not aware of. Usually I use `yarn upgrade` to upgrade all of my packages regularly. But in this case there was a dependency which forced serverless to stay on an outdated version. Only after proactively forcing serverless to upgrade to the latest version using `yarn upgrade serverless@2.61.0` and then afterwards calling once more `yarn upgrade` to also make the dependent packages based upon the new serverless version, I was able to upgrade serverless and its dependencies. After that, I deployed my services again and the error described above disappeared when calling my functions remotely.

I hope this also will help someone else who comes across this issue.

Comment: Didn't resolve my issue. I get `TypeError: events.some is not a function`, followed by a stack trace in various serverless packages in `node_modules` - nothing in my code/files. In fact the top of the stack references `/Users/bogeyman/project/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/package/compile/events/alexa-skill.js:30:20`
<b>
`Environment: darwin, node 17.0.1, framework 3.7.5 (local), plugin 6.1.5, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "aws-profile" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues`

Comment: Hey @BogeyMan, this seems to me like a different error not related to this issue here